# How to Link Sengrid to a Contact Form in Flask to Forward Email

Tags: python, email, flask, sendgrid

I am writing a web application and am trying to use sendgrid to handle email delivery services.

I am writing the application in Flask.

Right now I have a contact form, and my problem is that the email only gets delivered if I send the e-mail from my pre-approved e-mail address with sendgrid.  Obviously this is not good since everyone else who fills out the e-mail form will not have it go through.

Here's the code that I have:

**ROUTE**

```
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'apikey'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = os.environ.get('MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER')


@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contactpage():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Message sent")
        print(request.form.to_dict())
        m = message(request.form.to_dict())
        m.send()
    title = "Jonathan Bechtel contact form"
    description = "Contact Jonathan Bechtel with questions about teaching or working with him"
    return render_template("contact.html",
                            title=title,
                            description=description)
```

Here's my code for actually sending the e-mail:

```
import os
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail
class message():

    def __init__(self, message_data):
        for key in message_data:
            print(key, message_data[key])
            setattr(self, key, message_data[key])

    def send(self):
        message      = Mail(
        from_email   = self.email,
        to_emails    = 'jonathanbechtel@gmail.com',
        subject      = 'Sample Email Message',
        html_content = f'<strong>From: {self.email}</strong><br><strong>Reason: {self.reason}</strong><br><strong>Message:</strong>{self.message}')
        try:
            sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
            response = sg.send(message)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

If I set the `from` address in my contact form to my own the e-mail works fine.  However, if I use any other one the message does not go through and generates a `403` status code.

I think this means that I'm just not using the correct part of the API but am not sure where to start.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

SendGrid does not allow you to send emails from just any email address. I can see that in this case you are just trying to create a contact form that only sends emails to your email address so being able to send from any email address might be useful. But consider a form that allowed users to set the to and the from address and you can see how that might get abused.

You can [read more about sender identity and SendGrid here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity).

In the meantime, for your use-case here is what I would suggest.

Set the from email to your pre-approved email address, include the user's email address in the body of the email, as you are doing already. Then add the user's email as a reply-to email as well, that way you can respond to the email and it will be sent straight to the user.

I believe you can set the reply-to with the `mail` object's `reply_to` method:

```py
    def send(self):
        message      = Mail(
        from_email   = APPROVED_SENDGRID_EMAIL,
        to_emails    = 'jonathanbechtel@gmail.com',
        subject      = 'Sample Email Message',
        html_content = f'<strong>From: {self.email}</strong><br><strong>Reason: {self.reason}</strong><br><strong>Message:</strong>{self.message}')

        # Set the reply-to email
        message.reply_to(self.email)

        try:
            sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
            response = sg.send(message)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

See [the examples in the helper library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/16eb0c33c97f8ca293fbc0d8965afd87c0d2f99a/examples/helpers/mail_example.py#L218) for more detail.