# sendgrid/mail wont allow sending 'from' to be dynamically

Tags: sendgrid

I have a form on my portfolio that allows a user fill in a form with a question they have and send that to me by email.
When i try to use sendgrid it only allows me as a verified user to send emails from my own email address. but i want the 'from' field to be dynamically filled in by that user and then sent to me.

note: I also tried 'emailjs' but that works fine in development but fails in production.

Any suggestions on how to fix this or any other platforms i can use for that preferabally free since it is a hobby project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

You do need to use a verified email address to send emails from SendGrid, this is to stop people using a form like you describe to spoof anyone's email address.

A better idea is to send emails created in your form from a verified email address and set the reply-to address as the submitted email. That way you can send with SendGrid and then when you reply in your email client it will return to the person that submitted the form.

I added [more detail and example code (in Python) in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68341243/28376).